# What is a single word that describes a person who has a small amount of authority and exercises it heavy handedly with great self importance?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, nouns

For example, a supermarket cashier who strictly regulates customers’ compliance with their rules for proper check-out protocol, such as use of the order divider bar.

Comment: [I think this is a duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=Jobsworth).

Answer (score 4):

Given the example, I believe the word "jobsworth" expresses the exact meaning you are looking for. The word is used for a person who takes pride in discharging their duty, as may have been explicitly stated, with little or no concern for helpful or accommodating manner. Someone who would disregard concern for people over rightful discharge of their duties.

Hope it helps!

Comment: From the expression "It's more than my job's worth" [to let you break the rules].